# docker: not found in Jenkins docker build agent

Tags: docker, jenkins, dockerfile, jenkins-pipeline

I have Jenkins master running in swarm cluster as a container. My intention is dynamically provision a docker build agent using Jenkins declarative pipeline. When webhook is fired by GitHub, Jenkins master successfully provisioned a new docker build agent using the pipeline code. The master container has access to the docker commands. I have written pipeline code to build the docker agent that needs access to the docker running in the host. But While the docker build agent runs It logs "docker: not found".

docker compose file

```
version: "3"
services:
  jenkins:
    image: jenkins/jenkins:lts
    container_name: jenkins
    restart: on-failure
    user: root
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
      - "50000:50000"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - /usr/bin/docker:/usr/bin/docker
      - jenkins_home/_data:/var/jenkins_home

volumes:
  jenkins_home:
```

Jenkins Pipeline code:

```
pipeline {
  agent {
    docker { image 'node:16-alpine' 
    args '-v /usr/bin/docker:/usr/bin/docker -v  /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v - jenkins_home/_data:/var/jenkins_home'
      
    }
  }
  stages {
    stage('Test') {
      steps {
        sh 'docker version'
        
      }
    }

  }
}
```

log:

```
+ docker version
/var/jenkins_home/workspace/Docker Build Pipeline@tmp/durable-27d6d9c7/script.sh: line 1: docker: not found
```

I tried to implement ci/cd usinng jenins. When webhook will be fired jenkins will provision a docker build agent based on the written declarative pipeline

Comment: Bind-mounting compiled binaries like `/usr/bin/docker` may not work reliably, especially if the binary depends on shared libraries that aren't included in the image.  The linked question describes more robust approaches.